# Command to get the sql query of a BigQuery view

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a created a large number of views in BigQuery using standardSql. Now we need to see for the correctness of these created views.

Is there a bq command to get the sql query with which these views have been created in BigQuery?

This command will prevent manual effort of checking for the correctness of these views

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `show` command with the `view` flag.

e.g. `bq show --view <project>:<dataset>.<view>`

[image]

Comment: Hey with view definition, I meant the underlying sql query with which it has been created. bq show only gives the schema of the view. I have edited the question accordingly :)

Comment: No, it shows the SQL query too. Did you remember to use the `--view` flag?

Comment: Anyone know if its possible to get the same information from the bigquery console UI? i.e. is there a command I can issue in the SQL editor that brings back a view definition?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `--format=prettyjson` flag (instead of `--view`) so you can easily get the query content when running a script, for example:

`bq show --format=prettyjson <project>:<dataset>.<view>`